# Flash swf sometimes squashed when wmode = transparent or opaque on website

Tags: jquery, html, flash, swfobject

I have a problem on all browsers when I set wmode = transparent (or opaque) on a flash element on my site. I want to overlay some HTML content on top of the flash element, and this works fine, but for some reason the different components within the flash element are sometimes appearing squashed and not in the correct perspective. This does not happen all of the time, and does not happen at all if I remove the wmode parameter. I've never actually come across this before, and the fact that it is occasionally happening on all platforms and browsers means that this is definitely a problem I need to sort out. I use jQuery's Flash embed plugin to replace static content with the flash content, but this has never been a problem in the past.

Anyone have an idea what could be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the height and width of the element you're targeting with SWFObject in CSS.